# What would be the lebesgue measure of $T(E)$ when $\text{rank}(T)<n$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation, and let $m$ denote both the $m$- and $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measures.

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Since $T$ is Lipschitz, $T(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that $m(TE)=|\det(T)|m(E)$ when $n=m$.

Is there a formula to compute $m(TE)$ when $n\neq m$?

Comment: Any proper subspace has Lebesgue measure zero, so if $\operatorname{rk}T < n$, the formula is $m(TE) = 0$ :-). The map $T(x,y) = x$ maps $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ onto $\mathbb{R}$, hence maps a measure zero set to a set of infinite measure.

Comment: @copper.hat How do i prove that? Would you please write that as an answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace of dimension $d=\dim S < n$.

Let $v_k$ be an orthonormal basis such that $S=\operatorname{sp} \{ v_1,...,v_{d}\}$, or, in other words,
$S = \{V x | x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x_{d+1}=0,\cdots,\ x_n = 0 \}$, where $V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$ (since $V$ is orthogonal, we have $V^{-1} = V^T$).

Let $\Sigma = \{x | x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x_{d+1}=0,\cdots,\ x_n = 0 \}$.

Since $|\det V | = |\det V^T| = 1$, we see that $mS = m(V^T S) = m \Sigma$.

Now note that $\Sigma = \cup_k \{x | x \in [-k,k]^n, x_{d+1}=0,\cdots,x_n = 0 \} = [-k,k]^{d} \times \{0\}^{n-d}$.

If we let $R_k=[-k,k]^{d} \times \{0\}^{n-d}$, we see that $mR_k = 0$, and hence $m \Sigma = 0$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Oops, thanks for catching that!

Comment: No problem. It wouldn't hurt if it was explained in detail why we can assume $S$ has codimension $1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I thought the proof would be easier that way, but its the same. I have removed the codimension one assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If $m<n$, then $m(TE)=0$, as $TE$ lies in a $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

But of $m>n$ anything can happen. For example,

$E=\{(x,y): 0\le y\le (1+x^2)^{-1}\}$. Then $m(E)=\pi$. Let $T(x,y)=x$, Then $TE=\mathbb R$
and $m(TE)=\infty$.